# Convert JSON string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have for example the following JSON String :

```
'{"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":225,"top":155,"width":100,"height":50,"fill":"#000","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","selectable":true,"id":1,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":342,"top":81,"width":100,"height":50,"fill":"#000","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","selectable":true,"id":2,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":90,"top":138,"width":100,"height":50,"fill":"#000","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","selectable":"true","id":1,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":401,"top":271,"width":100,"height":50,"fill":"#000","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","selectable":true,"id":2,"rx":0,"ry":0}],"background":""}'
```

I need to store it in a javascript array in this format :

```
[ { type: 'rect',
originX: 'left',
originY: 'top',
left: 90,
top: 138,
width: 100,
height: 50,
fill: '#000',
stroke: 'blue',
strokeWidth: 1,
strokeDashArray: null,
strokeLineCap: 'butt',
strokeLineJoin: 'miter',
strokeMiterLimit: 10,
scaleX: 1,
scaleY: 1,
angle: 0,
flipX: false,
flipY: false,
opacity: 1,
shadow: null,
visible: true,
clipTo: null,
backgroundColor: '',
fillRule: 'nonzero',
globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over',
rx: 0,
ry: 0 },
{ type: 'rect',
originX: 'left',
originY: 'top',
left: 401,
top: 271,
width: 100,
height: 50,
fill: '#000',
stroke: 'blue',
strokeWidth: 1,
strokeDashArray: null,
strokeLineCap: 'butt',
strokeLineJoin: 'miter',
strokeMiterLimit: 10,
scaleX: 1,
scaleY: 1,
angle: 0,
flipX: false,
flipY: false,
opacity: 1,
shadow: null,
visible: true,
clipTo: null,
backgroundColor: '',
fillRule: 'nonzero',
globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over',
rx: 0,
ry: 0 } ]
```

Is it something possible? It's basically an array of objects that I need for my application. If you are wondering, the json string contains objects on a canvas.

Comment: So, `var resultArray = JSON.parse(yourJSON).objects;`?

Comment: I am getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: That's exactly what you should get if you call `console.log(resultArray.toString())`. Use resultArray[0].type to access property `type` of the first object in array.

Comment: Thanks :) got it working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

`JSON.parse`

[Some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

and than extract the value of `objects`:

`JSON.parse(yourJSONstring).objects`

To access on single object inside `objects` array you can:

```
var objectsArray = JSON.parse(yourJSONstring).objects;
var singleArray = objectsArray[0]; //for first object in array;
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t324Lhx6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse() method as follows:

```
var a = JSON.parse("json text OR json variable")['objects'];
```

This will extract array from Json text and store in array a.
Further u can use following to get any value out of it.

```
a[0];
```